# Reinstall or Reset Elementary OS loki 0.4.1 completely

Tags: release-loki

Don't know actually what i made to system, it now stuck at pantheon-greeter. Though i have no installation media around please help me to resolve this issue by reinstall or anything via terminal. 
**Actual Problem** - "After successful login to greeter black screen shown up for 2 seconds and then back to greeter login"

Answer (score 2):

(to add on to the first answer, as I'm unable to comment :eye_roll:)

To access a terminal, as you can't enter via GUI, use `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1`, and proceed to reinstall using `sudo apt install --reinstall elementary-desktop`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start this way:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall elementary-desktop
```

If that doensn't solve it, add a comment with the errors that appear.

Answer (score 0):

The error is very similar to what happened to me. And solve it in the following way:

I had been installing and modifying Elementary and I also changed the password of my user and restarted, what happened was that my / home directory was encrypted and by changing the password, Elementary could not de-encrypt / home with the new password. The quickest solution was to put the old password and everything went back to normal.

---

El error es muy parecido a lo que me ocurrio a mi. Y lo solucione de la siguiente forma:

Habia estado instalando y modificando Elementary y tambien cambie el password de mi usuario y reinicie, lo que ocurrio es que mi directorio /home estaba encriptado y al cambiar el password, Elementary no podia desincriptar /home con el nuevo password. La solucion mas rapida fue poner el antiguo password y todo volvio a la normalidad.